# Is it possible to write a custom valueOf method for primitives in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
Number.prototype.valueOf=function(){
  alert('works!');
}

'str'+123; // no alert
'str'+(new Number(123)); // alert
```

Is there a way to write custom `valueOf()` methods for primitives? I.e. is there a way to make `'str'+123` call `alert()`?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @jfriend00: Good question. I read the question as academic, but there may well be a pragmatic problem we could solve a different way.

Comment: I was playing around with ways to polyfill `Object.observe`, but it's mainly to learn more about Javascript. As for how this actually relates to `Object.observe`, it's fairly long winded...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I.e. is there a way to make `'str'+123` call `alert()`?

No, you have to do something to promote the primitive to its equivalent object first, which that line doesn't do (and I take it you don't want to do). The [addition operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) *(they call it that even when it's concatenation)* will use the spec's [`ToString` abstract operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8) to convert the number to a string. For numbers, the `ToString` abstract operation [does the steps below](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1), which don't involve using anything from the `Number` or `Object` prototype.

---

[The `ToString` abstract operation applied to numbers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1):

1. If *m* is **NaN**, return the String `"NaN"`.
2. If *m* is **+0** or **−0**, return the String `"0"`.
3. If *m* is less than zero, return the String concatenation of the String `"-"` and ToString(−*m*).
4. If *m* is infinity, return the String `"Infinity"`.
5. Otherwise, let *n*, *k*, and *s* be integers such that *k* ≥ 1, 10<sup>*k*−1</sup>
       ≤ *s* < 10<sup>*k*</sup>, the Number value for *s* × 10<sup>*n−k*</sup> is
       *m*, and *k* is as small as possible. Note that *k* is the number of digits in the decimal
       representation of *s*, that *s* is not divisible by 10, and that the least significant digit of *s* is
       not necessarily uniquely determined by these criteria.
6. If *k* ≤ *n* ≤ 21, return the String consisting of the *k* digits of the decimal representation
       of s (in order, with no leading zeroes), followed by *n−k* occurrences of the character
       ‘`0`’.
7. If 0 < n ≤ 21, return the String consisting of the most significant *n* digits of the decimal
       representation of *s*, followed by a decimal point ‘`.`’, followed by the remaining
       *k−n* digits of the decimal representation of *s*.
8. If −6 < n ≤ 0, return the String consisting of the character ‘`0`’, followed by a
       decimal point ‘`.`’, followed by −*n* occurrences of the character
       ‘`0`’, followed by the *k* digits of the decimal representation of *s*.
9. Otherwise, if *k* = 1, return the String consisting of the single digit of *s*, followed by lowercase
       character ‘`e`’, followed by a plus sign ‘`+`’ or minus sign
       ‘`−`’ according to whether *n*−1 is positive or negative, followed by the
       decimal representation of the integer abs(*n*−1) (with no leading zeroes).
10. Return the String consisting of the most significant digit of the decimal representation of *s*, followed by a
        decimal point ‘.’, followed by the remaining *k*−1 digits of the decimal representation of
        *s*, followed by the lowercase character ‘`e`’, followed by a plus sign
        ‘`+`’ or minus sign ‘`−`’ according to whether *n*−1 is
        positive or negative, followed by the decimal representation of the integer abs(*n*−1) (with no leading zeroes).